# Getting {"error": "invalid_grant" } in Django OAUTH when trying to generate a token using AUTHORIZATION CODE FLOW

Tags: django, oauth, django-authentication, django-oauth-toolkit

I'm trying to access token using authorization code flow. I'm using authorization_code as the grant type.
Following documentation at [Django OAuth](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#django)

Here's my code that's making the post request:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/o/token/' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=ngta3GGa3jP6Rmv5Tspj97Bk4aiitHgv1EQilCDS' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=zLwMyuXg7WCSFwUDYBxFP3QxHh5mF6xM2hBsKyvRbypac5lV7fl2NoFeeDG3afWWxLedA7qtzD2Mvf68qyBra3A4iUXXlDXJO4LvxuZv4UULU6NLWlObpD0ylQSXbwZD' \
--data-urlencode 'code=q4NfBMbyTNbcIQZ4j7SfgMWL898psv' \
--data-urlencode 'redirect_uri=http://localhost:8000/no/callback/' \
--data-urlencode 'code_verifier=b'\''SlJDWEgyRzNYMks0RTVQVDlRVkFaOFdDUkxHV1A3QURMTjNITFdaMTBLU0tWQkkzMUVWVEZFU0k='\''' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=authorization_code'
```

I'm expecting to get an access token when I make the post request, but I'm getting this error:
{
"error": "invalid_grant"
}

The grant is valid i.e not expired. Server time is in sync with machine time. Expiry time is 5 minutes but doesnt work even before it's expired.

Comment: Invalid grant could be a number of things are you sure your code hasnt been used before, what about the time on your machine is it in sync with NTP?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment. I've added some more details to the question. Can you guide me regarding NTP? How do I check that? And what do you mean by "code hasn't been used before"?